# Excel formula to check blank in range bases on criteria

Tags: excel, date

I have two ranges `K1:NK1` are dates of the years `(from 01/01/2015 to 12/31/2015)`, and `K2:NK2` has text. In cell `G2` I have the start date `01/01/2015` and `I2` has the end date `04/01/2015`.

I want to add a formula in cell `F1`, which check the start date and end date, whether there are any blanks between the two dates and give me the count.

I hope I have explained correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `=SUMPRODUCT((K2:NK2="")*(K1:NK1<=I2)*(K1:NK1>=G2))` if you want to include the start and end date, if you want to include them, use `=SUMPRODUCT((K2:NK2="")*(K1:NK1<I2)*(K1:NK1>G2))`.